# Simulating Conway's game of life but struggling to update initial conditions

Tags: python

Below is my progress. The first two functions work, but the final one does not. The final function serves to update the array provided by the first and second function. I do not want to change those. The first two functions just make an array with ones and zeroes and I need to update them according to these rules, but I'm getting no output.

```
import numpy as np
import random

#helper function no. 1

def seed_probabilities(i,j):
    
    rand_num = random.random()
    x = 1/(abs(i - j) + 2)

    if rand_num < x:
        y = 1
    else:
        y = 0
    return y


def create_world(nr, nc):

    #make array

    values = np.empty((nr,nc), dtype=int)


    #index array
    
    for i in range(0,nr):
        for j in range(0, nc):
            y = seed_probabilities(i,j)
            values[i,j]=y
    return values
        
values = create_world(6,7)

def one_generation_later(w):
    
    (nc, nr) = np.shape(w)

    for i in range(0,nr):
        for j in range(0, nc):
            L = [w[i,j-1], w[i,j+1], w[i-1,j], w[i-1,j-1], w[i-1,j+1], w[i+1,j], w[i+1, j-1], w[i+1, j+1]]
            neighborhood = []
            for k in L:
                if L[k]==1:
                    neighborhood.append(L[k])
                    num_alive = len(neighborhood)
                    if w[i,j] == 1 and num_alive > 3:
                        w[i,j] = 0
                    elif w[i,j] == 1 and num_alive <2:
                        w[i,j] = 0
                    elif w[i,j] == 1 and 2 < num_alive < 3:
                        w[i,j] = 1
                    elif w[i,j] == 0 and num_alive == 3:
                        w[i,j] = 1
    return w

one_generation_later(values)
```

I tried to pass my result from the second function into the third and loop through each point, finding the neighborhood at each point, and putting that into a list. I then used the length of the list to set up a series of conditions that would determine whether that point would be a 1 or a zero.

Comment: You cannot do this in place like this.  When you update a cell, you change the impact on the cells around it. You must create a NEW empty world, and copy the new state into that new world.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't understand how that'd help. What does that look like in practice?

Comment: One way it can look in practice is to make a copy of `w` in the first line of `one_generation_later`, and update `w` based on calculations on that copy - so that the copy is not changing as you are updating `w`.

Comment: Do you see the problem with your approach?  Let's say you update [2.2].  When you compute the neighbors for [2,3] and [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], they will all get the NEW value for [2,2], when they should be using the OLD value.

Comment: Your code `for k in L:` followed by `if L[k]==1:` is suspect. The loop is not going to give you *indexes*, but the *values* from L. The fact that they *are* valid indexes (since they're small integers) is preventing an exception that would make it clearer that something's going wrong. You probably want to compare `if k==1` (and also use `k` rather than `L[k]` in the next line). I'm also not sure the indentation of the the following lines makes any sense. It should probably be unindented to match the `for k in L` loop, rather than being inside of it.

Comment: I agree with @Blckknght, but I'd also just suggest a different approach. Think about this: (1) the values of w[i,j] are binary, right? (2) if you create a neighborhood for each L that contains the values that are equal to 1, then compute the length of that neighborhood, how is that related to `sum(L)`?